# How to change the font-size on resize to fit its parent box?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, font-size, onresize

[Here is the link of what I've done](http://foxklld.site88.net/test/nav/nav.html)
Some text on small resolution go out of the parent box and get clipped. How to fix it?
using jQuery would be preferable but I don't mind of JavaScript.
**UPDATE**

What I wanted to do is that when page is resized how to make text to fit its parent box?

Answer (score 3):

You can target screen sizes with css

```
@media screen and (min-width: 500px) and (max-width: 700px) {
body{
    font-size: x-small;
    }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 701px) and (max-width: 2000px) {
body{
    font-size: medium;
    }

}
```

Comment: Media queries rock; much better than javascript - unless you are wanting to keep everything on one line.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by using javascript or jquery. You can call resize function of jQuery

```
$(window).resize(function() {
  if($(this).height() < 640) {
      $(body).css("font-size","10pt");
  }
});
```

By using this way you can customize your logic....

Answer (score 0):

You can use [fittext.js](http://fittextjs.com/) for that. These other solutions would work. But if you change the browser size it could start getting really messed up.

Comment: ACTUALLY - for what you are doing - you just need to remove the widths on your link boxes and let them be auto. throw some padding on there. and a min-width to keep them uniform if you like. text-align center. line-height the same as the div height for vertical center.